# Can I enable my users to customize their home page tab?

Tags: administration, permissions, customization

AFAIK, users can only use HomePage Layouts that I create for them, or only change the Dashboard that they see. That's assuming they do not have the [Customize application](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_ui_settings.htm) permission.

Assuming I don't want to create and manage dashboards for my users, is it possible to give them the permissions to do that, without the setting? (which I think is an over kill for this usage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is no way to let your users edit their home page without granting this permission. However, if they can update reports and reports that would offer them a small level of flexibility, but not what you're likely to be after.

Comment: Thanks. this seems like such a needed customization issue. Some have reports, some don't, but each person likes his home page differently. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Home page layouts are tied to a user's profile - as a result, any change they made to the layout would impact all users associated with that user's profile. Beyond making changes to dashboards with the dashboard component, it's not really designed for end-user personalization.